# How redirect different portions of activity on different click in android

Tags: android, android-studio, reference

I need help, i want a functionality like make a reference of different portions in one activity with different clicks. For example, if an activity consist of 4 button at top in horizontal View and 4 portions (Part1, Paer2, Part3, Par4) are make in the same activity below this horizontal portion. i want when i click on button 1 it redirect to part1 portion (this all in 1 same activity). Same like other click on button 4 redirect to portion 4. I don't know what is the name of this functionality.

[Please go to this link to see the image](http://saadusman.androidstudent.net/CronaProject/screen_1.jpg)

The above link show you the picture we see at first time, the upper portion have option like "WRAPS", "DESI MEALS" etc. And if your click on "DESI MEALS" it switch or redirect to the that portion like i show in the following pic:

[Please go to this pic to see when i go to specfic portion](http://saadusman.androidstudent.net/CronaProject/screen_2.jpg)

I also see this functionality on websites, when there is menu at top of website and if we choose an option it redirect to that portion on same 1 page , i think that is one page website.

Comment: Can you maybe give a visual representation of what you want. I think that might make things a little bit more clear.

Comment: @SampurnG please check the updated question now

Comment: You can implement this using Fragments. I'll give you two main reasons why you should do it using them.
1. By using fragments, the Horizontal Navigation View that you've created won't have to be added to every other Activity/Layout too.
2. You said that you want all this in one activity, and frankly speaking i don't see any other(better) way for you to do it.

If you want it done using fragments, I can help. I see only one other wat to do it, using layouts and changing their visibility as per requirement but that just puts too much load on the UI thread and will make your application slow.

Answer (score 0):

As i understand i hope you're looking for fragments with tablayout on top  example like below[image: This is what you're looking]
if yes here is how to implement it https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-swipe-view

Comment: No that are not fragments and tablayout. This is something else, i khow the working of fragments and tablayout. Please check may updated answer i give some pictures examples.